# The SetSocketOption enumerations provided by the Framework have duplicate entries. How does this work?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

In setting up a `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` object, I am getting into using the `.Client.SetSocketOption()` function. The enumerations as found on [the MSN site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname?view=netframework-4.8), list the enumeration values. However there are many overlaps, i.e.:

```
Enum SocketOptionName
  Debug = 1
  IPOptions = 1
  NoChecksum = 1
  NoDelay = 1
  AcceptConnection = 2
  BsdUrgent = 2
  Expedited = 2
  HeaderIncluded = 2
End Enum
```

There doesn't seem to be a synonymous relationship between these settings, or any correlation between them and the `SocketOptionLevel` enumeration they are called with.

How does anything work when there is nothing to differentiate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be a synonymous relationship between these settings, or any correlation between them and the SocketOptionLevel enumeration they are called with.

The `SocketOptionName` values are generally not related to *each other*, no.  But they are related to the `SocketOptionLevel` values.  This is actually stated in the [`SocketOptionLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketoptionlevel?view=netcore-3.1) documentation:

> The `SocketOptionLevel` enumeration defines the socket option levels that can be passed to the `Socket.SetSocketOption` and `Socket.GetSocketOption` methods. **`SocketOptionName` enumerated values are grouped by `SocketOptionLevel`.**

`SocketOptionLevel` and `SocketOptionName` mirror the `level` and `optname` parameters of the WinSock [`setsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) API, where:

`SocketOptionLevel.Socket` (`level=SOL_SOCKET`) defines:

- `SocketOptionName.Debug` (`optname=SO_DEBUG`)
- `SocketOptionName.AcceptConnection` (`optname=SO_ACCEPTCONN`)
- ...

`SocketOptionLevel.IP` (`level=IPPROTO_IP`) defines:

- `SocketOptionName.IPOptions` (`optname=IP_OPTIONS`)
- `SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded` (`optname=IP_HDRINCL`)
- ...

`SocketOptionLevel.Udp` (`level=IPPROTO_UDP`) defines:

- `SocketOptionName.NoChecksum` (`optname=UDP_NOCHECKSUM`)
- ...

`SocketOptionLevel.Tcp` (`level=IPPROTO_TCP`) defines:

- `SocketOptionName.NoDelay` (`optname=TCP_NODELAY`)
- `SocketOptionName.BsdUrgent` (`optname=TCP_EXPEDITED_1122`) <sup>1</sup>
- `SocketOptionName.Expedited` (`optname=TCP_EXPEDITED_1122`) <sup>1</sup>
- ...

<sup>1: as `SocketOptionName.BsdUrgent` and `SocketOptionName.Expedited` both belong to `SocketOptionLevel.Tcp` and are both defined as 2, that means they are actually the same socket option just under different names.  In WinSock, the `IPPROTO_TCP` level has separate socket options defined for `TCP_BSDURGENT` (0x7000) and `TCP_EXPEDITED_1122` (0x0002).  Since `SocketOptionName.BsdUrgent` and `SocketOptionName.Expedited` are both defined as 2, they both represent `TCP_EXPEDITED_1122`.  The `SocketOptionName` documentation even says they both implement RFC 1222 (a typo, it really means RFC 1122).</sup>

> How does anything work when there is nothing to differentiate them?

They are differentiated by `SocketOptionLevel`.  It is the *combination* of `SocketOptionLevel` and `SocketOptionName` working together that defines a given socket option that can be queried/configured.  Each `SocketOptionLevel` defines 1 or more `SocketOptionName` values for itself.   So, there is room for overlapping `SocketOptionName` values for different `SocketOptionLevel` values.

Comment: Excellent answer. So in fact sending any of the SocketOptionName s that correspond to the right enumeration, will have the right effect against the SocketOptionLevel. Interesting they chose to break it out this way.

Comment: @JCollins like I said, the enums are just mirroring what the underlying WinSock `setsockopt()` API does, which itself mirrors the BSD socket API used on other platforms. Socket options are grouped by level, and within each level are multiple option names.  It is easier and extendable to have 1 do-all API than to have multiple per-level APIs.